# Check if two products belong to same invoice

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of Invoices, InvocicesLines and Products, and I'd like to select all the invoices that have two different products.

How can I do this?

Example:
Invoices table:

```
InvoiceNo  |   CustomerId    |  ...
=============+===============+========+
1          |   1             |   
2          |   2             |   
3          |   5             |   
4          |   7             |
```

InvoicesLines table:

```
InvoiceNo (FK) |   Id (PK)     |  ProductId |
===============+===============+============+
1              |   1           |    3       |
2              |   2           |    1       |
2              |   3           |    2       |
4              |   4           |    5       |
```

I need the invoices which have product 1 and 2:

```
InvoiceNo   |
============+
2           |
```

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Exactly two different products?  Two or more different products?  Something else?  Add sample data for best results here.

Answer (score 0):

You can join twice your invoices with your lines, and return the ones having different products. You must group the result.

```
select Invoices.IdInvoice
from Inovices
     inner join InvoicesLines as First on First.IdInvoice = Invoices.IdInvoice
     inner join InvoicesLines as Second on Second.IdInvoice = Invoice.IdInvoice
where First.IdProduct <> Second.IdProduct
group by Invoices.IdInvoice
```

This is going to return all the invoices with at least two different products.

But if you want to return the invoices with two different products, and only two different products, you can ensure it with a having clausule.

```
select Invoices.IdInvoice
from Inovices
     inner join InvoicesLines as First on First.IdInvoice = Invoices.IdInvoice
     inner join InvoicesLines as Second on Second.IdInvoice = Invoice.IdInvoice
where First.IdProduct <> Second.IdProduct
group by Invoices.IdInvoice
having count(Invoices.IdInvoice) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Group by Invoice number and use having clause to return only those invoices which has distinct count of products equal to 2 (or greater of 1, if you want "at least two products"):

```
select i.InvoiceNumber
from Inoices i
inner join InvoiceLines il on il.InvoiceId = i.InoiceId
group by i.InvoiceNumber
having count(distinct il.ProductId) = 2
```